# Batch Script To Identify Missing Numerical File Name

Tags: batch-file, filenames

I have a custom service that automatically generates files every 60 mins into a particular directory with part of the filename incrementing numerically, Eg:

```
File_00004.job
File_00003.job
File_00002.job
File_00001.job
```

Currently I have an issue where on occasion a file isn't generated, which results in gaps in the file sequence. This issue then causes a number of issues if not identified ASAP.

I'd like a batch file to identify if I have a gap in the file name sequence.
Tried looking for solutions from existing posts, but haven't found something that fits, so apologies if this has been covered elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files\t w o"

SET "mask=file_??????.job"
SET "lowest="
SET "highest="

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d /on "%sourcedir%\%mask%" '
 ) DO (
 IF NOT DEFINED lowest SET "lowest=%%~na"
 SET "highest=%%~na"
)
SET "lowest=%lowest:*_=1%"
SET "highest=%highest:*_=1%"

ECHO checking range %lowest:~1% to %highest:~1%

:: See whether an entry in the range is missing; report&create an empty file if so.

FOR /L %%a IN (%lowest%,1,%highest%) DO SET "name=%%a"&SET "name=file_!name:~1!.job"&IF NOT EXIST "%sourcedir%\!name!" echo !name! missing&(copy nul "%sourcedir%\!name!" >nul)

GOTO :EOF
```

Alternative structure for the `for /L` loop:

```
FOR /L %%a IN (%lowest%,1,%highest%) DO (
 SET "name=%%a"
 SET "name=file_!name:~1!.job"
 IF NOT EXIST "%sourcedir%\!name!" (
  echo !name! missing
  copy nul "%sourcedir%\!name!" >nul
  copy "d:\path to\template.file" "wherever\!name!" >nul
  copy "d:\path to\template.file" "anotherplace\!name!" >nul
  echo Batch is fun and powerful
  copy "d:\path to\template.file" "a third place\!name!" >nul
 )
)
```

The critical point is the positioning of the `(` - **must** be directly after **and on the same line as** `do` or `else` or the logical comparison clause of `if` and must be matched by a `)` (which doesn't *need* to be on its own line - I find it easier that way, to align indentation.) `)`s that are not intended to close a block need to be escaped with `^`, thus: `^)`

Comment: Many thanks for this!
I'll give it a try on my test system and let you know if you've saved the day!

Comment: Hello again, 

The script above works great to create the missing file and names it as required! Awesome! Didn't think i'd get a response so quickly!

Is it possible to create the missing file using a template file as i need the file to contain some basic text read by the custom service?

So essentially the script will identify a missing file, copy a template file and then rename it to the missing file name?

Comment: That'll take all of 10 seconds. You observe that the missing files are created as a zero-length. The `copy nul` is doing that. Changing `copy nul` to `copy "d:\your template\filename"` should copy the nominated file instead. The brackets around the `copy nul...>nul` are not required - I put them in to indicate that the `copy nul...` was optional. The `>nul` suppresses the `1 File(s) copied` message normally produced on a successful copy.

Comment: Only issue i have now is that the lowest and highest filenames change during the day. Currently these are manually set within the batch file you've provided.

Is there anyway for the batch file to set these automatically following a dir of the *.job files within the directory? Otherwise I could be creating unnecessary files etc.

Really appreciate your advice so far!

Comment: Should be self-adjusting.

Comment: Ignore that.... I'd wrongly inputted low and high file names, so it is self-adjusting! Awesome! Thank you!